# Hibernate Criteria restrict by aggregation

Tags: hibernate, join, subquery, aggregate-functions

### Background

We carry out tests on multiple items on a regular basis, which produce test results (either pass or fail). A single test can be applied to multiple items, and a single item can have multiple different tests carried out on it.

What we need to do is produce a list of all item/test combinations which are currently failing the test, and the number of failures since the last passfor each item/test combination.

Because of limitations with the system we're working with, the we must use the Hibernate Criteria API, not HQL. The data set is potentially very large.

### Problem

I have come up with the following approach:

Get the latest passing result from each test item, then inner join that with the testResults table to get ids of TestResults which fail since the last pass

```
SELECT 
  test.id, 
  item.id, 
  COUNT(item.id) 
FROM testResults 
INNER JOIN (SELECT item.id, test.id, MAX(testDate) FROM testResults GROUP BY item.id, test.id) AS lastPass
ON (lastPass.item.id = item.id AND lastPass.test.id = test.id)
GROUP BY
  test.id
  item.id
```

How can I create this inner join using the Criteria API? Subqueries only appear to work in the WHERE section, so aren't appropriate.

The following code creates a criteria which gets the date of the latest test for each test/item combination, but I need the TestResult which that date belongs to.

```
DetachedCriteria maxDate = new DetachedCriteria(TestResult.class, "maxDate");
maxDate.setProjection(Projections.projectionList()
    .add(Projections.max("testDate"))
    .add(Projections.groupProperty("test"))
    .add(Projections.groupProperty("item"))
    );
maxDate.add(Property.forName("maxDate.test").eqProperty("mainQuery.test"));
maxDate.add(Property.forName("maxDate.item").eqProperty("mainQuery.item"));
```

Any help would be much appreciated,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you're pretty close, you don't need to 'Property.forName' for referencing a main query from the subquery:

```
    Criteria mainQuery = getSession().createCriteria(TestResult.class, "mainQuery");

    DetachedCriteria maxDate = new DetachedCriteria(TestResult.class, "maxDate");
    maxDate.setProjection(Projections.projectionList()
            .add(Projections.max("testDate"))
            .add(Projections.groupProperty("test"))
            .add(Projections.groupProperty("item")));
    maxDate.add(Restrictions.eqProperty("maxDate.test", "mainQuery.test"));
    maxDate.add(Restrictions.eqProperty("maxDate.item", "mainQuery.item"));

    mainQuery.setProjection(Projections.projectionList()
            .add(Projections.groupProperty("test"))
            .add(Projections.groupProperty("item"))
            .add(Projections.rowCount()));

    result = mainQuery.list();

    //use some AliasToBeanResultTransformer to convert the projected result into beans
```

Try if this works...